# how to enable/disable a cron job via lambda in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

set up - a cron job to invoke a lambda via cloudformation. I need to enable/disable this cron job via another lambda, or even delete this based on some other process/trigger. is that possible or how can i do that?

```
cronJob:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
    ScheduleExpression: cron(0/15 * * * ? *) 
    Targets:
      - Arn:
          Fn::GetAtt: [ someLambdaFunction, "Arn" ] 
        Id:
          Ref: someLambdaFunction

someLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  ...
```

Comment: You disable it the same way you enabled it.

Comment: @Marcin- any code example or link you can direct me to

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you've an event rule which triggers the lambda (Let's call this 'Lambda A'). Now, you want to delete the event rule dynamically inside of another lambda (Let's call this 'Lambda B')

As you know, lambda will be triggered based on some event. I'm not sure about what do you mean by 'some process/trigger'.

You can even build a simple REST API backed by lambda - so that you can trigger ('Lambda B') which might use AWS SDK to delete the event rule.

You can do POST request to the REST API to delete the event rule(which would be done by Lambda)